# Aquaris 4.5e - which ebook reader works?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ebooks

I need an app that opens doc, epub or kindle files. From the Ubuntu Store I tried Document Viewer, Beru and Seshat and I am getting the same message when trying to download a file to read: 'Sorry, there aren't currently any apps installed that can handle this type of content'. 
Is there a reader that works on the Ubuntu phone?

Answer (score 1):

Beru has an inbuilt browser that let's you download epubs.
Using that instead of the system's browser should give no such error.

In the main menu choose "Download Books".
Then you have the option between "Project Gutenberg", "Open Library", "MobileRead Epubs", and "Search the Web"

To download epubs from a custom url choose the option "Search the Web" and enter the url you want to download from into the search field.
**Important**: Enter the url with leading http:// otherwise the url will not load.

[image: beru inbuilt browser to download epubs]

Comment: No success. I followed the instructions to download epubs via 'Search the Web' option and had a message saying 'Downloading Ebook' the progress bar was stuck on 75% and did not move from there - I waited 30 min and it was not completed in this time and no files were added to the Beru Library. Size of the file I was trying to download 132KB so I would expect this to be downloaded fairly quickly.

Comment: Hmm... Sorry to hear that :( Have you tried a different epub?

Comment: Thanks, I tried another similar size epub and the same issue again: download bar stuck at 76% this time. Document Viewer seems to work with pdf files so I will have to export all doc files to pdf for the time being. This is my uni work so it would be very useful to have a working reader.

Comment: Can't you copy the epub from a PC to the device?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to connect the Aquaris to an iMac, between the bug preventing from connecting via bluetooth, and iMac not detecting the phone via USB. I had some success with sending pdf files by email, downloading them on the phone and using Document Viewer to read them. This still requires using another device to download doc files and convert them to pdf so far from ideal. Preferably I would like to be able to download the epub or doc files from web straight onto the phone and be able to open them but I guess I will have to wait for this to be addressed by developers.

Answer (score 0):

Beru fails to download and open epub files from Gutenberg due to a bug in the Download Manager: https://github.com/rschroll/beru/issues/80